# Animate package with overlay picture

Tags: includegraphics, animate

I want to generate animated pdf where one image is used as background and animated part which is changed in layer above. Is this possible to do with [animate](https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) package?

Inspiration: [Faraday motor](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/watch-play/interactive/faraday-motor)

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
  \begin{animateinline}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}  % Backgroung image
    \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{18}{stick_}{0}{59}
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animateinline` and `\animategraphics` cannot be nested.

Use Ti*k*Z nodes to align the image parts:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop,scale=0.3]{25}
\multiframe{60}{i=0+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{down}};
    \ifthenelse{\i<15 \OR \i>45}{
      % stick in front of magnet
      \node at (-2,0.4) {\includegraphics{magnet}};
      \node at (-2,4.05) {\includegraphics{stick-\i}};
    }{
      % stick behind magnet
      \node at (-2,4.05) {\includegraphics{stick-\i}};
      \node at (-2,0.4) {\includegraphics{magnet}};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}\\[1ex]
\small Images: \textcopyright\ National High Magnetic Field Laboratory
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The images of the original example were downloaded and renamed with this shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..59}
do
    wget https://nationalmaglab.org/html5/MagLabU/source/faradaymotor/images/stickFrames/stick%20\($i\).png
    mv stick\ \($i\).png stick-$i.png
done
wget https://nationalmaglab.org/html5/MagLabU/source/faradaymotor/images/down.png
wget https://nationalmaglab.org/html5/MagLabU/source/faradaymotor/images/magnet.png
```

Comment: +1: This is amazing! In addition, I was not aware that an animated version of SVG exists.

Comment: Can you point me to where I can find this project on your profile (https://gitlab.com/agrahn)?

Comment: I uploaded only the SVG to my GitHub repo. If you want to produce it yourself, just add `dvisvgm` to the class options: `\documentclass[varwidth,dvisvgm]{standalone}`.  First, you need the images; download them with the commands in the code box at the bottom of my answer. Then run `dvilualatex` twice and finally `dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff2` on the DVI file.